# How can I debug my game on mobile device?

Tags: c#, android, monogame, debugging

I've been creating this game on my computer for months and everything works fine. But when I built the project and installed it into my android device, it doesn't run as smoothly. I don't wanna use the word "lag" as I don't think that's the correct term in this case. To be more specific, my game involves as series of platforms moving continuously from one end of the screen to another. When I play it on my mobile device, the platforms look a bit "shaky", as if the speed of the platform isn't exactly constant.

It's possible that this is happening due to my computer having a more powerful processor than my phone and hence, the performance isn't on par. But I don't see why that should be the case given that my scene isn't very complex. I've released an earlier version of this game on android before with roughly the same number of objects in my scene. It ran as smoothly on my phone as on my computer. Hence, I was expecting this version to be just as smooth.

To find out the problem, I made my game less complex by removing more objects from my scene and running it on my phone. But the performance was no different. The platforms still look quite "shaky" and their movement don't feel very smooth.

How can I isolate the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: The way your question was worded was a call for shots in the dark, and stack exchange sites are not super good at it. We can try and help you learn to fish, though.

Comment: This sounds like judder, which can arise from incorrectly adjusting for deltaTime or interfering with physics interpolation. Can you show us how you're moving your platforms currently (via a transform, rigidbody, or animation) and how you've configured the relevant components?